# Adding CheckBox to DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I have a DefaultTableModel which is populated with an Object[][] array.

Now I want to add a column with checkBoxes and perform operations accordingly.

When I add the checkbox into the Object[][] array and view it, I get text displayed

'javax.swing.JCheckBox[,0,0,0x0....', how do I get it to show a checkbox and add actions to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JTable have default checkbox renderer/editor for boolean values. Just make your `TableModel#getColumnClass` return `Boolean.class` for given column.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I get it to show a checkbox

See Uhlen's answer

> and add actions to it?

Use a TableModelListener. Something like:

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
{
    if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE)
    {
        int row = e.getFirstRow();
        int column = e.getColumn();

        if (column == ?)
        {
            TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
            Boolean value = (Boolean)model.getValueAt(row, column));

            if (value.booleanValue())
                // add your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you add that TableModelEvent to a TableModel?

Comment: @Teysz, `table.getModel.addTableModelListener(...);`

Answer (score 2):

You could also just get the class, instead of hard coding each return type. Here is an example for the override method :

```
 //create the table 
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
//override the method


               {
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colIndex) {

                return getValueAt(0, colIndex).getClass();

            }
```

Then, when you create the table you initialize it this way:

```
 data[i][12] = new Boolean(false);
```

which makes the box appear unticked :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom table cell renderer.

See here

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/CustRend.html

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot provide swing component as model object[] array. That should be registered as cell editor on column.

Anyway by default DefaultTableModel supports checkbox as editor for columns under which Boolean class type values are stored.

So, in the array pass Boolean.TRUE/Boolean.FALSE object and set table as editable. Then table automatically renders checkbox for you.

Are you need to register editor for each class type

Comment: It's most likely because you haven't implemented TableModel#getColumnClass, see my answer :)